# Dynamic multi column parent header and multi column child in expandable list view

Tags: android, view, expandable, lis

Please give me some idea to make Dynamic multi column parent header and multi column child in expandable list view in android.On arrow click child multi row must me expandaded.where parent and child has dynamic values.as shown in Image attached.
here red color marked color are header and yellow is child.
[Header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n98u2.png)
[Child image on expand header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcblG.png)

Comment: Please tell us, which technology you are using and show, what you already tried

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention about it i want to develop in android application.